# How to get the universal music player to detect on device music?

Tags: android

I'm trying to modify the universal music player app: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer

Since I'm trying to build this for AOSP 6.0, I have no Google Play Services or any other Google Apps on my device, and so cannot use any non-android api's or api's that depend on Google Libraries.

The "Music provider" class, seems to visit this url:

http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/music.json

As mentioned in this line:

```
private static final String CATALOG_URL =
    "http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/music.json";
```

This file contains a list of tracks that are hosted by Google online. It seems the app can stream these files, but for some reason it does not detect the music already on my device. Why is that ? How do I get the app to list the music tracks that are already on my device ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reimplement **MusicProvider** class and the setter to set your new **Source** from local device.
After you can use your new **mMusicProvider** variable in **MusicService** class and set the source you need in **MusicService's** **onLoadChildren** method.

More details you may see here:
[Change the source in UAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41042270/4516797)