# JSON with Android Universal Media Player Application (MediaPlayer Error 1)

Tags: android, json

{Novice Android Dev.}

I'm currently using Google's Open Source Media App found on [Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) to try and create my own media player for one of my own projects. However, one issue that I keep running into is that when I change the JSON file in RemoteJSON from

```
protected static final String CATALOG_URL =
    "http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/music.json";
```

to

```
protected static final String CATALOG_URL =
    "https://api.myjson.com/bins/2ir4d";
```

(using myjson.com to store the file)

it populates the information within the app but when one item is selected, it produces a MediaPlayer error 1 (-2147483648). (All I did was copy the JSON code from original Google URL and uploaded it to myjson)

My goal is to create my own JSON file with my own media content but I can't even get this one to work outside of the provided URL.

Any ideas?
Much obliged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the contents of the `music.json`, the `source` and `image` paths are relative paths, stored in the `http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media` directory.

In your case, there is no `https://api.myjson.com/bins/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3`, so any attempt to play that track will obviously fail. As seen in [the source code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/39fa286313639b5ce069e755c18762aaa1f59ea9/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/model/RemoteJSONSource.java#L93), the relative source and image name logic is only used when the values do not start with `http`.

You can temporarily prefix all of the sources and images with `http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/` to reuse the existing values until you host your own content.

Comment: I thought that the content was stored on https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music. Could you elaborate further, please? If I were to replicate with my own content, I would have a folder on my server that has the JSON file music.json and then all of the media in the same folder?

Comment: If you look at the source, the `site` attribute is never used. You can either use absolute links for the `source` and `image` or host all the files all in the same directory.

Comment: So then what is the site attribute even for if it is never used?

Comment: By definition, if it is never used (as it seems to be), then it is used for nothing.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand correctly, Google hosts the music.json file along with the respective media at http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media. The JSON in RemoteJson reads the file stored and then populates the data on the device. The reason why the URL that I made via myjson showed the data was because it was just hosting the JSON file but not the media. Right?

Comment: Yep! If the `source` or `image` fields don't start with `http`, then they are considered relative paths to the location of the JSON file and you didn't host the media files or images, hence why anything relying on those files fails.

Comment: Perfect. I think I got it. Would there be a reason as to why the seek gives the same error? Like the file stream perfectly. Play and Pause works fine and the album art is there but when I try and drag the seekbar, it gives that same error. However it does not give that error for the original google link. What is the difference?

Comment: You can certainly put a breakpoint in the code and compare the generated `MediaMetadataCompat` objects from one to the other. What you are describing now seems like a totally new issue worthy of a new question.

Answer (score 1):

First what you need - is to implement new uploading method from your backend.
You may do a similar method in class **RemoteJSONSource** with new url and parameters.
After you need to use your MusicProvider and call to upload method from your **MusicService** class.
If your goal is to create your own JSON - you may upload and retrieve your data this way in MusicService overrided method OnLoadChildren:

```
  @Override
  public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull final String parentMediaId,
                             @NonNull final Result<List<MediaItem>> result) {
      LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren: parentMediaId=", parentMediaId);

      // VTM
      getStoredUserData();
      mMusicProvider.setSource(new RemoteJSONSource(param1, param2, param3, param4));

result.detach();
         mMusicProvider.retrieveMediaAsync(new MusicProvider.Callback() {
             @Override
             public void onMusicCatalogReady(boolean success) {
                 result.sendResult(mMusicProvider.getChildren(parentMediaId,  getResources()));
             }
         }, param1, param2, param3, param4);

    }
```

I did this way, and my solution works. Been asking before how to improve and make this player more maintainable - but this is new implementation and less info about.

Comment: Couldn't I just change the parameters of the existing one? Why go through all the hassle if I could just host a JSON file and media content on my own server and do it that way. For example, I would host files and JSON at www.mydomain.org/services/music.json. Correct? Then I would just put that URL in the RemoteJSONSource. As long as the parameters match, it would work, right?

Comment: Hello. Right, if you need only change url - it is enough to change it in project. And, of course, implement the new Json parsing. In my case - i had additional params and made calls every time when the user change params in ui.

Comment: Could you explain how I would parse JSON info via track number? For some reason my JSON has the track information but the app is not ordering them correctly? Not sure why

Comment: First goal to prepare tracks - is parsing JSON and creating the list of POJO's, second - creating Media Items (Tracks) with Builder help. You should better to see how the RemoteJSONSource class works. You may parse JSON array with GSON lib and finally create the list of items for your MediaPlayer. Better to look and analyze the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084816/json-not-parsing-tracks-in-correct-order