# JSON not parsing tracks in correct order

Tags: android, json

I created a JSON file of which my Android app pulls the list and puts the hymn and puts them in a specific order. Previously, I had all my files in copticchurch-library.org/media. This included all the media and the JSON file itself. However, I would like to do more organization seeing as it might get a little disorganized when adding more media.

I created a new directory at copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers.
This directory has all the media (mp3 and album art) pertaining to that folder. The JSON folder is still in copticchurch-library.org/media

**Issue** 
Why is it that it does not list the tracks in the correct order on the app?

JSON Code

```
{"music" : [ 
{ "title" : "Mercy and Compassion",
  "album" : "Standard Deacon Responses",
  "artist" : "Cantor Ibrahim Ayad",
  "genre" : "Standard Deacon Responses",
  "source" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers/Mercy_compassion.mp3",
  "image" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers/image1.jpg",
  "trackNumber" : 1,
  "totalTrackCount" : 5,
  "duration" : 57,
  "site" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers"
},
{ "title" : "Litany of the Departed",
  "album" : "Standard Deacon Responses",
  "artist" : "Cantor Ibrahim Ayad",
  "genre" : "Standard Deacon Responses",
  "source" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers/Litany_departed.mp3",
  "image" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers/image2.jpg",
  "trackNumber" : 2,
  "totalTrackCount" : 5,
  "duration" : 95,
  "site" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers"
},
{ "title" : "Litany of the Sick",
  "album" : "Standard Deacon Responses",
  "artist" : "Cantor Ibrahim Ayad",
  "genre" : "Standard Deacon Responses",
  "source" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers/Litany_sick.mp3",
  "image" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers/image3.jpg",
  "trackNumber" : 3,
  "totalTrackCount" : 5,
  "duration" : 43,
  "site" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers"
},
    { "title" : "Litany of the Travelers",
  "album" : "Standard Deacon Responses",
  "artist" : "Cantor Ibrahim Ayad",
  "genre" : "Standard Deacon Responses",
  "source" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers/Litany_travlers.mp3",
  "image" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers/image4.jpg",
  "trackNumber" : 4,
  "totalTrackCount" : 5,
  "duration" : 61,
  "site" : "http://copticchurch-library.org/media/matinsandvespers"
},
```

Based on the code and the screenshot, everything is out of order and I can't figure out why.

[image: Screenshot of disordered media]

Strangely it works when I put everything in one place but when I want to create sub-dir, it looses its order.

I've tried putting the music.json file in that directory but still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**
I've added more tracks to the reverted method and the tracks are still out of order.

**Edit 2**

[RemoteJSON.java](http://pastebin.com/FHKNaVRh)

[MusicProvider.java](http://pastebin.com/BZVKnF67)

**Edit 3 
[Github project repo](https://github.com/AbanoubG/arabicreader-app)**

Comment: Show the relevant code

Comment: because i have not able for checking your problem . you are using retrofit for retrieve json

Comment: Just added all the relevant code and the repo for the app on github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me figure out how to do it. This is the code that he wrote which ended up working.

```
} for (String key : newMusicListByGenre.keySet())
        {
            Collections.sort(newMusicListByGenre.get(key), new Comparator<MediaMetadataCompat>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(MediaMetadataCompat track1, MediaMetadataCompat track2) {
                    return track1.getLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TRACK_NUMBER) < track2.getLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TRACK_NUMBER) ? -1 : 1;
                }
            });
        }
        mMusicListByGenre = newMusicListByGenre;


        list.add(m.metadata);
    }
    mMusicListByGenre = newMusicListByGenre;

}
```